# программное изменение свойств PercentRelativeLayout

Tags: android

Здраствуйте. помогите пожалуйста.
 есть такая вот разметка

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_percent_price"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text=" ___1000"
    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_litle"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    app:layout_marginBottomPercent="20%" />
```

как изменить значение layout_marginBottomPercent у TextView програмно?

Comment: TextView находится в обвёртке android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout

Answer (score 1):

```
TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.tv_percent_price);
PercentRelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (PercentRelativeLayout.LayoutParams) textView.getLayoutParams();
// This will currently return null, if it was not constructed from XML.
PercentLayoutHelper.PercentLayoutInfo info = params.getPercentLayoutInfo();
info.marginBottomPercent= 0.60f;
textView.requestLayout();
```

Comment: большое спасибо. всё получилось.